# SQL Server Import plugin not starting

Tags: sql-server, import, plugins

In Azure data studio,
using SQL Server Import plugin,
Microsoft SQL Server Import for Azure Data Studio
I always receive this message, and the plugin never start

[image]

Comment: We'll need more details. if you expand the error it should give more details or tell you where to look (possibly in the Output pane).

Comment: Have you ever had this plugin start correctly? Possibly it's trying to download other components to complete the Flat File Import Service's installation and is encountering a Corporate Proxy Server. In the HTTP world 407 is a Proxy Authentication Required error response.